# When to Nest a union inside a structure as a design choice

Tags: c, user-interface, design-patterns, network-programming

This might be a naive question , I have clear Idea about structures and unions ,and I have seen the use of nesting a union inside a structure in network programming and User Interface programming. But Since these codes are there from long back , I am not able to figure out what would be the design choice or advantage that leads to this decision. Why would I nest a union inside a structure and what would be the advantages , or is this a legacy carry over.The codes I have seen is mainly C.
The sample code looks like this

```
typedef struct   
{  
int address1;  
int addresslocation;  
int addresstype;  
}ITEM;  

typedef struct application  
{   
    union  
    {  
        ITEM const *arr1;  
        ITEM *arr2;  
    }initial_array;  
}APPLN;
```

Comment: It's quite common when designing variant-type structures.

Comment: I am not very much aware of the variant type structure , can you elaborate a bit if possible

Comment: Most commonly you have a struct + array inside a union, to alias the same memory with different variables. Anyway, this is too broad. Perhaps you could post a code example?

Comment: What is it about putting a union inside of a structure that invalidates the advantages of using one outside of a structure?

Comment: E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-tagvariant

Comment: At least you need a selector in the struct to tell which element of the union is in use, e.g. `struct X { int selector; union Y{int y; float f;};};`

Comment: *when to nest*    Simple, when the needs of the application will be better served with the nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem not to have any concern about unions in general, so it's unclear why you're asking about unions appearing as structure members.  If they're useful data structures in general (and I contend that they are), then putting them inside a structure does not reduce their usefulness.

In fact, putting unions inside structures can *increase* their usefulness.  One of the key restrictions on the use of unions is that they hold only one member at a time, and (with some caveats) you're permitted to read only the member most recently stored.  But how does one know which member that is?  One way is to put the union in a structure along with another member that indicates which union member currently contains a value.  This pattern goes by various names, among them "tagged union" and "variant record".

But the specific case you asked about is murkier:

> ```
> typedef struct application  
> {   
>     union  
>     {  
>         ITEM const *arr1;  
>         ITEM *arr2;  
>     }initial_array;  
> }APPLN;
> ```

A structure type with only one member has pretty limited usefulness.  It has the same alignment requirement as all other structure types (which could, in principle, be different from the alignment requirement for unions), so perhaps there's an application for that.  Also, if the one member is an array then wrapping it in a structure permits passing and returning it by value, but that's not your case.

For the most part, instead of defining a structure type with only one member, I would prefer to use the member's type directly.  Especially so if I'm defining a `typedef` alias to refer to the type.

Also, the specific form of the union in your example is a little concerning. The only members are pointers to `const` and non-`const` versions of the same data type, and, especially without a tag field, the main use I see for that is to conceal non-conforming program actions from the compiler, so as to avoid warnings and / or errors that in fact are well justified.